# ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view with trigger and union view

Tags: oracle, triggers, union

**Hi I created two tables**

```
 CREATE TABLE "LCM_001"."LCM_BDT$ACT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SHORTDESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR), 
    "LONGDESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
    "VALIDFROM" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, 
    "VALIDTO" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, 
    "VERSION" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
   )
```

The second table is exactly the same as the first, so I created it with "

```
create table LCM_BDT$HIST as select * from LCM_BDT$ACT where 1=0;
```

Then I created a view

```
select * from LCM_BDT$ACT 
Union
select * from LCM_BDT$HIST
```

Then I wrote a a instead of trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER LCM_BDT_DML
  instead of insert 
  on LCM_BDT
  -- for each row
declare
    vAct LCM_BDT$ACT%rowtype;
    vHist LCM_BDT$HIST%rowtype; 
  begin
    IF INSERTING THEN
      select BDT_SEQ.nextval into vAct.id from dual;
      vAct.SHORTDESCRIPTION := :new.SHORTDESCRIPTION;
      vAct.LONGDESCRIPTION := :new.LONGDESCRIPTION;
      vAct.VALIDFROM := sysdate;
      vAct.VALIDTO := TO_TIMESTAMP('31.12.3999','DD.MM.YYYY');
      vAct.Version := 1;
      Insert into LCM_BDT$ACT values vAct;
    END IF;

    IF UPDATING THEN
--      vHist.ID  := :old.ID;
--      vHist.SHORTDESCRIPTION := :old.SHORTDESCRIPTION;
--      vHist.LONGDESCRIPTION := :old.LONGDESCRIPTION;
--      vHist.VALIDFROM := :old.VALIDFROM;
--      vHist.VALIDTO := sysdate;
--      vHist.VERSION := :old.Version;
--      
--      Insert into LCM_BDT$ACT values vAct;
--    -- new record
--      UPDATE LCM_BDT$HIST set 
--      vAct.SHORTDESCRIPTION := :new.SHORTDESCRIPTION;
--      vAct.LONGDESCRIPTION := :new.LONGDESCRIPTION;
--      vAct.VALIDFROM := sysdate;
--      vAct.VALIDTO := TO_TIMESTAMP('31.12.3999','DD.MM.YYYY');
--      vAct.Version := :old.Version +1;
--      Insert into LCM_BDT$HIST values vHist;

    delete from LCM_BDT where id = :old.ID;
    END IF;
END LCM_BDT_DML;
```

**The Problem is that I alway got an SQL error:**

SQL-Fehler: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
01732. 00000 -  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"
*Cause:
*Action:

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: Please post the code causing this error. Maybe an update?

Answer (score 2):

Your `if updating` branch includes:

```
delete from LCM_BDT where id = :old.ID;
```

That is trying to delete from the same view this trigger is against, not either of the underlying tables. (Presumably, if the inserts into `BDT$ACT` and `BDT$HIST` weren't commented out, you would really want to delete the old `BDT$ACT` record? Or both - perhaps eventually via the view.)

As the trigger is only `instead of insert`, that can't actually be reached; but any attempt to update or delete the view will get an error, since the trigger doesn't cover either of those operations.

You can allow update and delete (which will need a `when deleting` section by changing the trigger to be:

```
instead of insert or update or delete
on LCM_BDT
```